# Calc value count in few columns of DataFrame (Pandas Python)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataFrame:

```
   id   code_1   code_2
0  11    1451     ffx
1  15    2233     ffx 
2  24    1451     mmg
3  15    1451     ffx
```

I need get number of each code value (for all code_1 values and all code_2 values) for unique id. For example:

```
   id   1451   2233   ...   ffx  mmg   ...
0  11    1       0    ...    1    0    ...
1  15    1       1    ...    2    0    ...
2  24    1       0    ...    0    1    ...
```

I do this code:

```
y = data.groupby('id')
        .apply(lambda x: x[['code_1', 'code_2']].unstack().value_counts()) 
        .unstack()
```

But i think that something wrong because number of result table columns less then number of varians code_1 and code_2.

Comment: I don't see the problem here. For column `code_1`, there are _two_ unique values and for `code_2` there are _two_ unique values. So in total, there should be *four* columns. The output of your code contains 4 columns

Comment: is not output of my code, it's just example that i needed

Answer (score 1):

Consider merging pivot_tables using the aggfunc *len* for counts.

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

data = '''
id   code_1   code_2
11    1451     ffx
15    2233     ffx 
24    1451     mmg
15    1451     ffx'''

df = pd.read_table(StringIO(data), sep="\s+")

df = pd.merge(df[['id', 'code_1']].pivot_table(index='id', columns='code_1', aggfunc=len).\
                                               reset_index(drop=True),
              df[['id', 'code_2']].pivot_table(index='id', columns='code_2', aggfunc=len).\
                                               reset_index(drop=True),
              left_index=True, right_index=True).fillna(0)

#    1451  2233  ffx  mmg
# 0   1.0   0.0  1.0  0.0
# 1   1.0   1.0  2.0  0.0
# 2   1.0   0.0  0.0  1.0
```